# How to deal with link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, hyperlinks

Once again my answer was deleted because I posted it (a long time ago) with a few links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943047/575643

As a heavy Stack Overflow user I always downvote/flag-for-deletion some of the useless ones but some, a few, are still helpful mainly because the links still work properly for the answer (also my case).

This is not a complain post, far from that! But what kind of criteria apply to this?

In my point of view copy-and-paste texts, docs, code, etc. from another page here are useless and duplication because it can get outdated pretty fast. Providing a link could lead the user to a good overview or at least point them in the right direction. On the other hand, links can be broken and then it would make sense to delete such answers.

So what's the conclusion? To link or not to link?

Comment: If the answer isn't an answer when the link is broken, it should be removed.

Comment: Don't edit meta information into your question.  Your question is where you ask your question, nothing else.

Comment: *complaining about downvotes without a comment leads to more downvotes without a comment*

Comment: I'm downvoting because, as the tooltip says, the question lacks research. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: ***Provide context for links**  Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: sometimes being a dr. obvious is needed @KevinB

Comment: once looks nobody follow this properly whats the point @MikeMcCaughan? its random, people who have no clue about topics just post links and on the other side people who have no clue about the subject flag and delete answers

Comment: So, let's not obey any laws because some people don't follow them?

Comment: @MarceloFilho: so first you demand that people explain their downvotes, and then when someone does, you call into question the competence of those who downvoted. That attitude right there is why voting is anonymous and will never require commenting, because *in many cases* you just end up in an argument with the poster feeling that the voting is not justified. You'll just have to accept that the motivation for votes is *up to the voter*, and no-one else. Getting into arguments over it (or being insulting towards those that vote) will only lead to escalation.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: So wait....you know the rule but you forego it because others also forego it... That sounds like a GREAT way to change anything about our system here... In any case. Downvoted for lack of research. It's easy to read on meta and see why link only answers aren't useful. And the fact that the links aren't dead (yet) doesn't change squat

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just want to have room for a good and healthy discussion about the subject, I'm not angry or mad, just want to talk about it... ;)

Answer (score 25):

Your "answer" doesn't answer the question. You just link to a state diagram and a table with 39 rows without saying why they're relevant to the question being asked. Just saying that you're linking to the MediaPlayer documentation isn't nearly enough context. Sure, the answer is there *somewhere*, but where?

Now look at [ZakiMak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926911/1288). He points out exactly where the problem is in the OP's code, and provides a detailed explanation and example code of his own. That's what a good answer looks like.

Comment: I'm only using my one as example, not mandatory that I'm right or wrong. But you had a good point although I still not able to see the difference, in my example I only didn't duplicate the code or gave the fish straight way to the guy, I was trying to teach him how to fish ;)

Comment: Nope, you gave him a piece of paper with directions to a fish

Comment: @MarceloFilho You didn't even give him directions to a fish. You gave him directions to the ocean and expected him to find the fish. We can all do that already. Telling people where to find the documentation is not particularly insightful. Assume people already know where it's at.